# IIS pool threads are blocked on malloc and free, COM+

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, deadlock, freeze

I'm working with COM objects from asp.net page logic using the windows server 2008 server x64 and IIS 7. Often, after few hours work, users can't has access to the site, because it is blocked until the iisreset is not done.

Here is piece of crash/hang reports from DebugDiag tool:

Detected possible blocking or leaked critical section at 0x053901f8 owned by thread 41 in w3wp.dmp
Impact of this lock
47,13% of threads blocked (about 20 threads)

The following functions are trying to enter this critical section

```
ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeap+18c6
ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap+1334
```

It was in time interop objects for management com.
The stack trace is like follows:

```
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+a    
ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+ea    
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+f4    
ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeap+18c6    
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+151    
msvcr100!malloc+5b
```

or

```
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+a    
ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+ea    
ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+f4    
ntdll!RtlpFreeHeap+1334    
ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+1a2    
kernel32!HeapFree+a    
msvcr100!free+1c
```

I'm guessing, there are corruptions in the management memory. Site worked on virtual machine under VMware Server.

Does anyone has similar experience on this before?

Thanks a lot!